FFmpeg dynamic inputs SRT (video protocol) select for one output SRT (video protocol)
Is it possible, after linking a SRT to SRT connection, using two inputs for one output, to switch between the inputs while it remains connected to the output, without having to lose the connection?
example: (x)input1 ()input2 to output
With some script I want it to change to ipunt 2 without losing the outgoing connection

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Please update your question with what you've tried. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!
